# Are there exceptionally rare items in Diablo 3 like the high runes in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-iii

The high runes in Diablo 2 had a very low drop rate, such that most players would never see one drop, even if they've been playing since release. Does Diablo 3 have any similar items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest items in similarity would be the Radiant Star gems.

The difference becomes that these items must be crafted, unlike say a Zod rune which had a very very small chance of appearing on the highest end opponents.

The similarity is that you need to use a large amount of lesser gems to create these gems very much like creating a Zod from lesser runes.

Comment: Except that you can't create Zod from lesser runes, the high level runes couldn't be created like this.

Comment: @bwarner On the ladder or in single player they certainly could be, though it was a later patch that allowed it.

Comment: @bwarner see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/29797/10260

Answer (score 6):

At this time there exists 5 amulets that are considered extremely rare. The drop rates on these are extremely low. [The Star of Azkaranth](https://www.diablowiki.net/The_Star_of_Azkaranth) having the lowest drop rate of every item in the game.

[Source](http://www.diablohub.com/database/item/the-star-of-azkaranth/information/):

> During the RoS playtest stream that occured on Tuesday February 18th,
> Travis Day stated that [The Star of Azkaranth](https://www.diablowiki.net/The_Star_of_Azkaranth) will be the rarest drop in Reaper of
> Souls. The reason for its rareness is because so many enemies use fire
> attacks in the game, which means that this amulet is the most usefull
> and most desired of the "Prevent all element damage" amulets.

- [Talisman of Aranoch](https://www.diablowiki.net/Talisman_of_Aranoch)
- [Countess Julias Cameo](https://www.diablowiki.net/Countess_Julia%27s_Cameo)
- [Maras Kaleidoscope](https://www.diablowiki.net/Mara%27s_Kaleidoscope)
- [The Star of Azkaranth](https://www.diablowiki.net/The_Star_of_Azkaranth)
- [Xephirian Amulet](https://www.diablowiki.net/Xephirian_Amulet)

*Current Patch 2.0.5.*

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

There's one more tier of items above 'Rare' titled 'Legendary'. If you check the auction house, you can see some players have acquired some already.

Comment: If there's already several legendary, then I doubt they're exceptionally rare :p

Comment: Perhaps not exceptionally rare, but certainly they lie within the parameter of 'rare'.